# How to add a scrollpane in java SE?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i want to add a scroll pane into my graph frame.I tried through several ways but not succeed.I am new to java so Kindly post with code and suggestion. Thanks
code is here

```
public class GraphDraw extends JFrame {
int width;
int height;
 JPanel setPanel;
 JFrame jf=new JFrame();

ArrayList<Node> nodes;
ArrayList<edge> edges;

public GraphDraw() { //Constructor
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jf.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new Canvas()));
nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
edges = new ArrayList<edge>();
width = 30;
height = 30;
}

public GraphDraw(String name) { //Construct with label
this.setTitle(name);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
edges = new ArrayList<edge>();
width = 30;
height = 30;
}

class Node {


public Node(String myName, int myX, int myY) {

}
}

class edge {


public edge(int ii, int jj) {

}
}

public void addNode(String name, int x, int y) { 
//add a node at pixel (x,y)

}
public void addEdge(int i, int j) {
//add an edge between nodes i and j

}

public void paint(Graphics g) { // draw the nodes and edges
FontMetrics f = g.getFontMetrics();
}}}
```

Now instance of this class in some other class such as

```
public class showGraph extends JFrame {

public int x=250;
public int y=50;


public showGraph(ArrayList<Structure> array){
GraphDraw frame = new GraphDraw("My Window"); 
frame.setBounds(600,10,600,800);    
frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

       //logics 
 }
}
```

### **__________________________**

Latest code:

```
public class GraphDraw extends JFrame {

   int width;
   int height;
   ArrayList<Node> nodes;
   ArrayList<edge> edges;

   public GraphDraw() { // Constructor
      // this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
      edges = new ArrayList<edge>();
      width = 30;
      height = 30;
   }

   public GraphDraw(String name) { // Construct with label
      this.setTitle(name);
      // this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
      edges = new ArrayList<edge>();
      width = 30;
      height = 30;
   }

   class Node {

      int x, y;
      String name;

      public Node(String myName, int myX, int myY) {
         x = myX;
         y = myY;
         name = myName;
      }
   }

   class edge {

      int i, j;

      public edge(int ii, int jj) {
         i = ii;
         j = jj;
      }
   }

   public void addNode(String name, int x, int y) {
      // add a node at pixel (x,y)
      nodes.add(new Node(name, x, y));
      this.repaint();
   }

   public void addEdge(int i, int j) {
      // add an edge between nodes i and j
      edges.add(new edge(i, j));
      this.repaint();
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) { // draw the nodes and edges
      FontMetrics f = g.getFontMetrics();
      int nodeHeight = Math.max(height, f.getHeight());

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      for (edge e : edges) {
         g.drawLine(nodes.get(e.i).x, nodes.get(e.i).y, nodes.get(e.j).x,
               nodes.get(e.j).y);
      }

      for (Node n : nodes) {
         int nodeWidth = Math.max(width, f.stringWidth(n.name) + width / 2);
         g.setColor(Color.white);
         g.fillOval(n.x - nodeWidth / 2, n.y - nodeHeight / 2, nodeWidth,
               nodeHeight);
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawOval(n.x - nodeWidth / 2, n.y - nodeHeight / 2, nodeWidth,
               nodeHeight);

         g.drawString(n.name, n.x - f.stringWidth(n.name) / 2,
               n.y + f.getHeight() / 2);
      }
   }
}
```

showGraph.java

```
public class showGraph {

   public int pos_x = 250;
   public int pos_y = 50;

   public showGraph(ArrayList<Structure> array) {

      GraphDraw frame = new GraphDraw("My Graph");
      frame.setBounds(600, 10, 600, 800);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.addNode("Node-1", pos_x, pos_y);
      frame.addNode("Node-2", pos_x, pos_y + 100);
      frame.addEdge(0, 1);

   }
}
```

Comment: Please tell the details -- for instance, you seem to be putting a Canvas object into a JScrollPane -- why? And what exactly are you trying to put into a JScrollPane? Also, please don't ask for code. You might get code, but you might not, and instead only get recommendations. You will learn more, however if you do the brunt of coding yourself.

Comment: Also you have classes that extend JFrame, but then seem to be creating another JFrame, jf, that you never display -- why? What's the logic behind your code?

Comment: i want scroll able window/frame where i'll add some graphs

Comment: You will want to read the tutorial that Kayaman has linked to as well as other tutorials. Please check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) for some decent Swing resources.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is totally random. You're extending `JFrames`, creating `JFrames`, you put a `Canvas` in a `JScrollPane` for no reason. You're writing random things without thinking what you're doing. That's not a good way to get anything sensible done.

The [JScrollPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) is here, but I suggest you read the other tutorials as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several big problems, but biggest is here:

```
public class GraphDraw extends JFrame {
   // ...
   JFrame jf=new JFrame();
   // ...

   public GraphDraw() { //Constructor
      // ...
      jf.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new Canvas()));
      // ...
   }
```

Your GraphDraw class extends JFrame, and your code looks like you intend to use it as a JFrame, and yet inexplicably, you create a completely **new** and different JFrame, here called jf, give it a JScrollPane that is given some Canvas object that contains nothing of use. It looks like random code thrown against the wall.

You don't want to do this. Instead, create your JScrollPane and pass into its constructor something that you actually want to scroll, a JPanel with your graphics on it for instance, and then add that to the `this` the JFrame that is the class.  For instance:

```
public class GraphDraw extends JFrame {
   // JFrame jf=new JFrame(); // get rid of this guy

   public GraphDraw() { //Constructor
      // ...
      getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(myJPanelWithGraphics));
      // ...
   }
```

where myJPanelWithGraphics is a JPanel that has your actual graphs on it.

Most important -- read the tutorials that you've been given links to. As I've learned from my own personal experience, guessing at this stuff never works. Here are some decent Swing resources:

- [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html): the main tutorial where you should start.
- [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html): how to create Swing GUI's
- [StackOverflow Swing Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

---

**Edit**
Suggestions regarding your latest code:

- Don't draw directly in a JFrame
- Instead draw in a JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` override method.
- Be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first method call of your override above. This will tell Swing to do housekeeping drawing on the component including removal of dirty pixels.
- Then add this drawing JPanel into your JScrollPane's viewport by passing it into the JScrollPane's constructor.
- And then add the JScrollPane into a JFrame's contentPane.

Comment: @user3531482: If you need more detailed help, then you will want to improve your question. There's no way anyone can guess what might be wrong based on what you've posted so far. If you've tried to make changes to your code and it's still not working, then you will want to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23444947/edit), show your latest code as an addition to the bottom of the question, and give more detailed descriptions of just what isn't working.

Comment: ^yup my way of asking quest was wrong...i posted again kindly visit here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445973/java-scrollpanes-how-to-add-in-a-frame-begginer-programmer